# Error: `nullptr` was not declared in this scope. Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, library

I try to use [this](https://github.com/ivanseidel/ArduinoThread) *ArduinoThread* library. In the Arduino I go *Sketch->Import Library->ArduinoThread*. After that I have the following line in the beginning of the sketch:

```
#include <ThreadController.h>
#include <Thread.h>
#include <StaticThreadController.h>
```

I leave `setup()` and `loop()` empty and try to verify or upload the sketch on my Arduino board. But I get the following errors:
[image]

Is this about the library or I do something wrong?

Comment: How old is your Arduino setup?  Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24845127/error-constexpr-does-not-name-a-type-m-arduino-ide would help

Comment: I am using Arduino 1.8.5. I think it is pretty recent, isn't it?

Comment: It works with 1.6.8 and 1.6.9 those are the ones I have and it compiles without errors.

Comment: What do you have selected in the **Tools > Board** menu? You should always post text as text, not a picture of text.

Comment: Sorry for that. It turned out I was using old version of Arduino IDE indeed. Seemingly, I have installed IDE twice. Two different versions. One manually and other is by `apt-get`. `arduino` command, of course, was for the old version. Now it works. Thank you.

Comment: Please write an answer to your question to help out anyone else who also encounters this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I installed Arduino IDE in two different ways (only god knows why). The first one was via using of manager `apt-get` and other was manually via downloading, unzipping and installation through the `install.sh` file.
It seems that on Ubuntu 14.04 the

```
sudo apt-get install arduino
```

command provides an installation of an old version of Arduino IDE.
So eventually I was launching Arduino IDE by `arduino` command in my terminal (actually I was using d-menu in i3). No surprise it ran the old one installed by `apt-get`. I just removed that version by

```
sudo apt-get remove arduino
```

And now I am using executable `arduino` inside unzipped folder. Actually, I am not using Arduino IDE explicitly at all. I am using a Makefile from [here](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile).